# Onde fica o arquivo de erro log no symfony?

Tags: log, symfony

Estou executando um projeto, no localhost mesmo, feito com Symfony para corrigir um erro e para isso gostaria de ver o arquivo com o erro no log mas não sei onde fica. Alguém sabe me dizer? Obrigada.

Comment: Bem-vinda ao Stackoverflow. Qual é a versão do Symfony?

Comment: Obrigada @WallaceMaxters , Symfony 3.2.13

Answer (score 0):

O log de erros fico em "/var/log"

Comment: Como não fornece uma resposta à Pergunta? O ficheiro de log de erros fica exactamente nesse pasta.